# Uncomfortable Interview

Tags: professionalism, interviewing

I recenlty gave an interview to a person, for a position in the dept I supervise.  The interviewee asked a question that I was somewhat uncomfortable with, as it had racial overtones. It was not necessarily a racist comment, but I did not feel it was appropriate.  I must add, that this candidate is very well suited for the job, and I would have considered pretty much perfect except for the question that was asked.

I reported this to my manager who reported it to HR.
HR went straight to the recruiter who provided this candidate. Then someone else from the company called the candidate and asked him about it. And then called the candidate's references. Of course it was denied, but I was immediately "outed".

The company still wants to hire this candidate, whom would be a direct report to me. I am somewhat afraid of retaliation now. When I mentioned this to HR, I was told - in so many words - that if the candidate was hired and could not be controlled it would be failure on my part as a supervisor.

I am hearing  a lot about liability for the candidate.

What about for me? Are there work place protections for people who report incidents like this, that they feel are inappropriate? I feel like I've really been thrown under the bus on this one.

Comment: Please can you tag your country, advice may vary. Also, Are you 100% sure you did not misread the intention of the interviewee's question?

Comment: It would actually help a lot if you told us the interviewee's question

Comment: What kind of protection are you expecting here? What retaliation are you afraid of? You just honestly reported the details of the interview. How HR chose to handle this was entirely up to them. If they cause problems when hired, just handle those appropriately. If you're more worried about getting fired over this or legal liability, you really should talk to a lawyer (although I don't exactly see much to worry about here yet).

Comment: What exactly was the question that he asked?  It is important for us to judge this ourselves.

Comment: Missing all kinds of details that would help us answer the question. What country/jurisdiction are you in? Specifically, what was the candidate's question that you picked up racist overtones from?

Comment: @Dukeling since an accusation of racism can literally ruin a person's career, one must be very careful at even suggesting that someone is racist or there exists a very real possibility of a defamation lawsuit.

Comment: @OlinLathrop No, it's not. **The details of the remark are irrelevant.** It's sufficiently serious that the hiring company actually informed the recruiter, speculation and arguments on what the remark was would serve no purpose here.

Comment: Final CV cast. There's a distinct lack of an actual question here. And the particulars of your situations are also rather confusing. You're hiring for a position you manage. You found a candidate who has shown questionable character to the point that you wouldn't hire them, but you're being *told* to hire him anyway? And then your management is also saying that *you* are responsible if the hire ends up not working out? Ludicrous. And yet I don't doubt that it's true. But **it would help if you could clarify the players involved here and why they're not respecting your judgement.**

Answer (score 3):

Once again **HR IS NOT YOUR FRIEND**  Yes, you raised this to your management, but since it was an HR issue, the same philosophy applies.

Your mistake seems to have been that you raised what appears to have been a non-issue by being overly cautious.  However, since the issue involved race, it **had** to be escalated due to liability issues.  Now, your company seems to be a bit peeved.

It is, in some respects, understandable, because as far as the company is concerned, you wasted a bunch of time and created a tempest in a teapot.

The reason liability is now an issue is that the company has been officially informed of this person's potential, but he hasn't actually done anything.

The reason that there is no protection for you is you acted prematurely.  A definite possibility of a firm maybe is no reason to exclude someone.  If your company doesn't hire him, it sounds like they might get hit for defamation or some other charge, and they **will** have to pay out.  If they do hire him, and it turns out he **is** a troublemaker, then they get hit for hiring someone who has been flagged as a potential problem and are liable for knowingly doing so.

You've put your company into a potential lose-lose situation.  It stinks, but from your company's perspective, you've caused them unnecessary grief.

Comment: How do we know it's unnecessary grief without knowing what the question was?

Comment: @thebluefox from the OP's question, it's all right there from the fact that he said it had "overtones" to it getting escalated all the way to the recruiting firm and then coming back down on him like a ton of bricks.  Unless the company he works for is entirely insane, they view it as unnecessary.  If they are insane, he should find a sane firm to work for.